# Select random rows in mysql with whose column sum should meet condition value

Tags: mysql

I need to have random questions from my question bank.I have a table `tbl_mq` with columns `mq_id`, course, unit, question, marks. I need to randomize such that the sum of the marks is 20.
Here what i tried :

```
Select * 
from tbl_mq 
where sum(marks)=20 
order by rand()
```

Example :

```
22, '3CA1151', 'I', 'Fisrt question', 5
20, '3CA1151', 'I', 'Second question', 10
15, '3CA1151', 'I', 'Thisrd question', 10
24, '3CA1151', 'I', '4th question', 5
13, '3CA1151', 'I', 'jyuyt', 10
14, '3CA1151', 'I', 'fghfgh', 12
```

Result should be

```
22, '3CA1151', 'I', 'Fisrt question', 5
20, '3CA1151', 'I', 'Second question', 10
24, '3CA1151', 'I', '4th question', 5
or 
20, '3CA1151', 'I', 'Second question', 10
15, '3CA1151', 'I', 'Thisrd question', 10
```

Finally i need questions such that the total marks of that columns is 20. Can any one help please?

Comment: I don't think this can be done in a query - you need to be able to re-select different questions if the random selection doesn't have a total mark of 20 and also make sure you don't select duplicates. What programming language are you using?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using c# language .But for that we have to set the limit ryt? As i am randomly selecting question i can't set limit as it is depends on marks.

Comment: I haven't used C# in a long time, but I expect you could run a query that would return an array of all questions and you could then pick questions at random and check that your total does not exceed your limit. It might be worth looking at MySQL's CREATE PROCEDURE to see if this will do what you want.